# MonoTouch Enterprise Licensing

Tags: licensing, xamarin.ios, enterprise

How many developers can work together with MonoTouch Enterprise Licensing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one seat per license, but they do have volume licensing aswell.

http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/topics/80275-store-faq/articles

Answer (score 1):

Only one developer can use the enterprise license at one time.

This license is assigned to your company though, instead of a specific developer, so if you hire somebody else, or the current developer leaves the team, another one can work on the project without having to purchase a new license.